# Unable to access session storage from browser using a state provider parent component in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: blazor, session-state, state-management, asp.net-core-7.0

I am able to set the session storage but not access it. I am working in a Blazor server app. I have even debugged and found that userId does not get fetched and its value gets set to 0 when the `OnInitializedAsync` method of `StateProvider` component is called.

Here is my code for state provider parent component in `StateProvider.razor`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedSessionStorage ProtectedSessionStore

@if (isLoaded)
{
    <CascadingValue Value="@this">
        @ChildContent
    </CascadingValue>
}
else
{
    <p>Loading...</p>
}

@code {
    private bool isLoaded;
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    public int userId { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var result = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<int>("userId");
        userId = result.Success ? result.Value : 0;
        isLoaded = true;
    }

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        await ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("userId", userId);
    }
}
```

I have also set render-mode to server in `_Host.cshtml` to handle prerendering as said in the docs:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace UserApplication.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="UserApplication.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally I have used the state provider in the child component:

```
<h3>ShowData</h3>
@page "/showdata"

<h1>@StateProvider?.userId</h1>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private StateProvider? StateProvider { get; set; }
}
```

No error occurs but the `userId` value is shown as zero here. It is perfectly set in the browser when I login, but it does not get fetched properly.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this. Thanks.